# place span next to the last line of an editable div

Tags: html, css

I try to do something similar to the location label in the Facebook message box which is always next to the last text line while we are typing.

[image]

I tried with a two inline `spans`, but the location label appears next to the right border of the text `span` as you can see.

[image]

Without any Javascript to dynamically place the location label, is it possible to do something similar to Facebook?

Take a look at [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s1rt191q/)

HTML:

```
<div>
    <span class="textarea" class="status" contenteditable="true">foo
foobarfoobar
bar</span>
    <span contenteditable="false"> — at Montréal</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div{
    width: 190px; 
    border: 1px solid #dedee0;
    padding: 10px;
}

.textarea{
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    display: inline-block
}

.location{
  display: inline-block  
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/s1rt191q/2/

Answer (score 0):

And if you use inline only?: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/s1rt191q/1/)

```
.textarea{
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    display: inline;
}

.location{
  display: inline;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that when you press shift + enter, it Will place the location on a new line..

Comment: Do you know how to place the location span next to the the last line of content when you press enter or shift + enter? @fcastillo

Comment: Non I just changed white-space: pre-wrap to white-space: pre-line and it works. Thank you

Comment: BTW, you jquery snippet didn't work (press shift + enter a couple of times ;) )

Answer (score 0):

Inside `.textarea`, change to `display: inline;`

Also, I don't know if this was intentional, but you never applied the "location" class to the second span.

Comment: The problem is that when you press shift + enter, it Will place the location on a new line. Do you know how to place the location span next to the the last line of content when you press enter or shift + enter?